# can't able to delete data in coredata in iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-data

After  [managedObjectContext deleteObject:device]; still showing data in device object.can't delete the data from database.how can i delete the data

```
if (managedObjectContext == nil) 
{ 
    managedObjectContext = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
    NSLog(@"After managedObjectContext: %@",  managedObjectContext);
}

NSError *error;

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Reserve" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]; 
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity]; 


//    NSSortDescriptor tells defines how to sort the fetched results
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"number" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
NSLog(@"sort count%d",[sortDescriptors count]);


fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];


NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(number = %d)", [sender tag]];

// [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
[fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
self.fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];      
NSLog(@"Count of array::::%d",[fetchedObjects count]);
NSManagedObject *device = [fetchedObjects lastObject];  
NSLog(@"device::::%@",device);

[managedObjectContext deleteObject:device];

 NSLog(@"device::::%@",[fetchedObjects lastObject]);
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you save the context after deleting the object from it?

Comment: no i do not save the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting the object (`device`) from the context will not cause it to automatically disappear off the end of the previous result-set (`fetchedObjects`).  The array that you fetch will contain whatever objects existed at the time it was fetched.  It does not update itself automatically.

Have you tried running your fetch request again after deleting the object from the context and then checking to see if the device still appears in the result-set?  Also, if you really want the object to stay deleted, it's a good idea to `save` your context as well.

If you want, you can add a delegate to the `NSFetchedResultsController`, which will call back into your code whenever the result-set changes.  You can then use the notification as a cue to reload the array.